# Site redirects to https://developer.salesforce.com/500 after login

Tags: login, login-errors

I am new to salesforce, and when I try to login the site from `https://login.salesforce.com/?startURL=%2Fsetup%2Fsecur%2FRemoteAccessAuthorizationPage.apexp%3Fsource%3D...` it redirects to `https://developer.salesforce.com/500` after checking my username and password.

I am getting the following error page.

> We're sorry, but something went wrong.
>   If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try just [login.salesforce.com](https://login.salesforce.com) without all that gunk at the end.

Notice in the URL you provided there is a "startURL" parameter. This is what is telling Salesforce what page to drop you on when you are done. Removing that parameter will fix your issue.